# Download many files in QT

Tags: qt, qt4, symbian

I want to download some files using QT but I don't know what's the best way to do it. I was thinking of a DownloadQueueItem that will manage the QNetworkRequest/QNetworkReply for each file and a QList, where I will insert the DownloadQueueItems in order to be able to delete them after they download.

Is my thinking correct? Could you show how you would do it in code? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to use is the QNetworkAccessManager.  It will take a request, download it and emit a signal when it's ready.  See [for sample code and documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qnetworkaccessmanager.html).